# Group data by foreign key and date with total by date

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

I need help to select daily payments made and group by the organization and date.
Group by date, then the total number of payments and the sum total amount of payments for each day
Tables are as follows,

```
organizations 
-----------------------------
|    id       |    name     |
+-------------+-------------+
|    1        |    org_1    |
+-------------+-------------+
|    2        |    org_2    |
+-------------+-------------+
|    3        |    org_2    |
-----------------------------

payments
------------------------------------------------------------
|   id      |  org_id    |    amount   |    date_created   |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------------+
|    1      |    2       |    20       |   2020-11-06      |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------------+
|    2      |    2       |    10       |   2020-11-06      |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------------+
|    3      |    1       |    50       |   2020-11-05      |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------------+
|    4      |    2       |    10       |   2020-11-05      |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected Result

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| date_created   |   total_amount |   num_payments    |  org_1    |    org_2    |    org_3   |
+----------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|   2020-11-06   |     30.00      |      2            |    0      |     2       |    0       |
+----------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|   2020-11-05   |     60.00      |      2            |    1      |     1       |    0       |
+----------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select p.date_created,
    sum(p.amount) as total_amount,
    count(*) as num_payments,
    sum(case when o.name = 'org_1' then p.amount else 0 end) as org_1,
    sum(case when o.name = 'org_2' then p.amount else 0 end) as org_2,
    sum(case when o.name = 'org_3' then p.amount else 0 end) as org_3
from payments p
inner join organizations o on o.id = p.org_id
group by p.date_created
```

Comment: thank you but your query limits the number of organizations to only these 3 what happens if a new organizations is added

Comment: @Wells: then you need to add more conditional expressions to the `select` clause. Otherwise, you need dynamic SQL, that is much more complicated.